# Editing Single Characters in Text File (Java)

Tags: java, file, text, edit, writer

I have the following text file with either 0 or 1 in first then two strings all three are separated by commas:

```
0     ,     Bx     ,     Cz
1     ,     By     ,     Cx
0     ,     Bz     ,     Cy
etc.  ,     etc.   ,     etc.
```

And I have the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Manager {

 static Scanner scanner;

 public Manager() {

 }

 public static void chooseFile(String thisFile) {
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new File(thisDeck));
        scanner.useDelimiter(",");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

 static String getB() {
     String b = null;
     if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
         String a = scanner.next();
         do {
             if (a.equals("1")) {
                 scanner.nextLine();
                 a = scanner.next();
             }
             if (a.equals("0")) {
                b = scanner.next();
             }
         } while (scanner.hasNextLine() && a.equals("1"));
     }
     if (!scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        b = “Done.”;
     }
     return b;
 }

 static String getC() {
     String c = null;
     if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        c = scanner.nextLine().substring(2);    
     } else {
        c = “Done.”;
     }
     return c;
 }

 static void changeA1() {
    //Here I want to change a value in the first "column" A to 1
    //The row/line to be changed is the one that the scanner just passed
 }
 static void changeA0() {
    //Here I want to change a value in the first "column" A to 0
    //The row/line to be changed is the one that the scanner just passed
 }

}
```

My question is how can I change the value A to 0 or 1? The GUI (which calls this class) only allows the user to change the value-A after calling the getB() and then getC(), so the scanner is at the end of the line when the functions for changing the value A of a line will be called. Can I edit value-A with a second scanner or is there another way?

Comment: It is really diffult to understand your question, maybe because of missing code, maybe because I  don't manage to understand which output you like, try to edit your question and I'm sure that someone online will give you an answer

Comment: Explain what kind of change you want to achieve: Changing all "a" to zeroes? Changing all "a" to ones? Change zeros to ones and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` doesn't allow any modification of a file at all. You'll have to use a `FileWriter` or another class for this purpose. And it's in general not recommendable to use two objects to modify and read a file at the same time. Most classes don't even allow this, due to the fact that the file-content will usually be streamed (the file is open all the time and a new chunk is loaded when the complete buffer has been processed).

The simplest approach would most likely be a `RandomAccessFile` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

This can aswell speed up the complete code quite a lot, if the values are always fixed-size. But it's rather difficult to recommend anything without more information about the structure of the file.